# How to convert numbers from exponential to normal form in Android?

Tags: java, android

How to convert numbers from exponential to normal form in [Android](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_%28operating_system%29)?

Comment: Try giving the apt tags, so that you will get the best results for your question.

Comment: @deepthi: Can you provide an example? (in the question itself)

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you are asking is how do you do this in Java and by normal I'll assume you mean as either a float or double. Java doesn't have a built in exponential type, but you can display them in that form when viewing them. I'll assume the numbers that you want "converted" are a string so this is what you can do:

```
double d = Double.parseDouble("1.23e+4");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
double d=123456789012346;

DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
OutputItem.setText(df.format(d));
```